# How to save bits to a file in Go

Tags: encoding, go, bit

I want to serialise some data in Go and I have to write the individual bits. (Specifically for Huffman encoding). What is the best way to do this? The most obvious way would be to just take eight bits at a time and shift the first one 7 places to the left, six with the next one and so on.

I was wondering whether or not there was a more idiomatic way to do this, possibly a function in the standard library. I've had a look at encoding/gob, however it does not seem to offer the control I wish, for example writing a slice of 4 booleans (which I would have thought corresponded to bits) outputed 24 bytes. I'm guessing it has numbers which signify slice start, boolean next etc.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Dou you want to read back the serialized data in Go only? Ore some other languages/tools too? What is wrong with encoding/gob if your "bits" are actual bools in a slice?

Comment: It would be nice for it to be read back in other languages. The problem with gob is the resulting file would be far larger than if it was just the bits

Comment: Okay, than just encode your bits into one or several uint's and write them to disc either as bytes or as ascii number. BTW: even if 24 bytes is much larger than 1 byte it is still **nothing**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encoding/gob is a binary encoding for go values. It has nothing to do what so ever with bit operations. It's main purpose is to provide a performant solution for transfering go datastructures over network connections etc (especially for the rpc package).

golang's internal representation of slices is a struct containing a pointer to an array (of appropriate type), and two ints, one for `len`gth (i.e. the number of elements in the slice) and `cap`acity (i.e. the ammount of memory allocated for the array.

I don't think there is support in the standard library for what you want to accomplish. So I think you need to write your own implementation, as you suggested yourself.

Maybe you can put the relevant code in a separate package and share it, go is a young language and needs implemetions like this, I think.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: No worries, one more question as I'm not too familiar with Go idioms. If I were to make this into a package the most obvious thing to do would be to have a function that writes to a slice of bytes and one that reads from a slice of bytes.

I was wondering if it would be better to have something that implements the reader/writer interface?

Comment: @matio2matio, the various encoders in Go tend to have an api conducive to how they're typically used. Most generally encode/decode using `[]byte`. Browse through the encoding packages like encoding/binary end encoding/base64.